Where should data validation happen? - Model or Serializer?
I am working on a project where data validation is crucial. I have noticed tutorials placing validation logic either on the data model itself or within a separate serializer class. This inconsistency is causing confusion.
Can you clarify the pros and cons of each approach for data validation, and when it might be better to use one over the other?

Models don't validate data proactively. But typically a ModelSerializer looks at the validators of the fields of a model, and runs these.

Imagine you have a form for users to enter their email address.
For Model Validation: It is Like having a security personnel at the email address gate. The security personnel checks if it's filled in and unique. This is good for basic rules on a single model.
For Serializer Validation: It is Like having a more advanced security system at the email gate. It checks multiple stuffs, E.g if it ends in your company domain only (yourcompany.com). Good for complex rules or reusing them for different things (E.g forms and API calls).
What choice?
Simple rules, one model? Model validation is fine.
Complicated rules, need it in different places? Serializer validation is better.

This is a subjective topic.
Data validation is crucial - meaning that no corrupted or "bad" data should ever enter the system.
The question is: Who is entering data into the system and what data flow you use in your application?
If you have basic rest web-service & public api & backend for frontend which accepts data from real users than it's really important to write your validation on two layers: input layer (meaning when data reaches your system through some kind of request) and data layer as well (database constraints).
F.E. imagine an example where you'd like your users to have some unique property attached to them (let it be a phone number). You'd query the database to check if this number exists and then proceed/respond with 400/Bad Request in your serializer. But what if your serializer has a bug in it and the data enters the system? Then you have unique constraint on database level, you'd get the IntegrityError and will see that you have a breach in your input validation.
Imagine you have other type of system, higl-load service (data-logger) that only store stuff that IoT devices are constantly streaming to it(amqp, http, etc) and your goal is only to store VALID data and do it with maximum throughput. In this case there's no point in having a complex serializer with understandable response because you'd query the database on each request and slow down the capacity of your service, just implement data validation on DB level (constraints, etc) and handle db errors.
Basically always it depends on what you do and what your end goal. Hope it helps.
